# ABC: Killed outputprep failure: No file or1200_top_mapped.blif

Tags: yosys

I am using  Qflow 1.1 to synthesize place and route a digital system,  unfortunately i get a problem at stage ABC , the synth.log output is :

```
46.5.1. Executing ABC.
ERROR: ABC: execution of command "/usr/bin/berkeley-abc -s -f /tmp/yosys-abc-xvRO2o/abc.script 2>&1" failed: return code 137.
Running ABC command: <yosys-exe-dir>/berkeley-abc -s -f <abc-temp-dir>/abc.script 2>&1
ABC: ABC command line: "source <abc-temp-dir>/abc.script".
ABC: 
ABC: + read_blif <abc-temp-dir>/input.blif 
ABC: + read_lib -w /usr/share/qflow/tech/osu035/osu035_stdcells.lib 
ABC: Parsing finished successfully.  Parsing time =     0.00 sec
ABC: Scl_LibertyReadGenlib() skipped sequential cell "DFFNEGX1".
ABC: Scl_LibertyReadGenlib() skipped sequential cell "DFFPOSX1".
ABC: Scl_LibertyReadGenlib() skipped sequential cell "DFFSR".
ABC: Scl_LibertyReadGenlib() skipped sequential cell "LATCH".
ABC: Scl_LibertyReadGenlib() skipped three-state cell "PADINOUT".
ABC: Scl_LibertyReadGenlib() skipped three-state cell "TBUFX1".
ABC: Scl_LibertyReadGenlib() skipped three-state cell "TBUFX2".
ABC: Scl_LibertyReadGenlib() skipped cell "PADFC" without logic function.
ABC: Scl_LibertyReadGenlib() skipped cell "PADNC" without logic function.
ABC: Scl_LibertyReadGenlib() skipped cell "PADVDD" without logic function.
ABC: Scl_LibertyReadGenlib() skipped cell "PADGND" without logic function.
ABC: Library "osu035_stdcells" from "/usr/share/qflow/tech/osu035/osu035_stdcells.lib" has 28 cells (11 skipped: 4 seq; 3 tri-state; 4 no func).  Time =     0.01 sec
ABC: Memory =    0.38 MB. Time =     0.01 sec
ABC: Warning: Detected 2 multi-output gates (for example, "FAX1").
ABC: + strash 
ABC: + scorr 
ABC: Error: The network is combinational (run "fraig" or "fraig_sweep").
ABC: + ifraig 
ABC: + retime 
ABC: + strash 
ABC: + dch -f 
ABC: + map -M 1 
ABC: Killed
outputprep failure:  No file or1200_top_mapped.blif.
Premature exit.
```

Please does someone has any idea to resolve this problem?

Comment: Since it says "Killed" and not something like "Segmentation Fault": Is it possible that you ran out of memory and the system OOM killer terminated the ABC process? You should see a message like "Out of memory: Killed process .." in `dmesg` output (or the /var/log/... file your distribution writes those log messages to).

Comment: Thank you sir, it is really there is not enough of memory. But the new problem is : "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"??

Comment: If you upload your Yosys Synthesis script and design sources I can have a look at it..

Comment: I recently had this problem, and it turned out the issue was with Qflow's installation. Looking at the log files, it said that it was calling `/usr/share/qflow/bin/yosys-abc`, which was symlinked to `/usr/bin/yosys-abc`. However, that file did not exist for me, so I changed the symlink to `abc`'s actual location (for me, `/usr/bin/abc`), and this fixed the issue.